# How pass custom parameters to FullCalendar events feed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar

According to [FullCalendar docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/) there is possible to pass parameters to JSON feed. I'd like to pass as parameters some HTML elements values. I don't undestand why but some of them passing successfully however others are not.
For example this one passing:

```
<select id="ticketsnumber" class="form-control" name="pax">
   <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
```

But this one not:

```
<select id="optionsfrom" class="form-control" name="depplace">
   <option value="" selected="">Откуда...</option>
   <option class="bold info" name="Country" value="460">Россия</option>
   <option name="City" value="1">Москва (MOW)</option>
   <option class="bold info" name="Country" value="359">Болгария</option>
   <option name="City" value="539">ВАРНА ()</option>
   <option class="bold info" name="Country" value="359">Болгария</option>
   <option name="City" value="559">СОФИЯ ()</option>
   <option class="bold info" name="Country" value="84">Испания</option>
   <option name="City" value="19">Барселона (BCN)</option>
   <option class="bold info" name="Country" value="7">США</option>
   <option name="City" value="95">Нью-Йорк (N.Y)</option>
   <option class="bold info" name="Country" value="53">Тайланд</option>
   <option name="City" value="220">Бангкок (BKK)</option>
</select>
```

This is how I call events feed:

```
         eventSources: [
                {
                    url: "@Url.Content("~/Home/GetQuota")",
                    data: {
                        pax: $("select[name='pax'] option:selected").val(),
                        fromtype: $("select[name='depplace'] option:selected").attr("name"),
                        fromcode: $("select[name='depplace'] option:selected").val(),
                        totype: $("select[name='arrplace'] option:selected").attr("name"),
                        tocode: $("select[name='arrplace'] option:selected").val(),
                        airservice: $("input[name='tariffs']").val()        
                    },
                    type: "POST",
                    error: function () {
                        alert('Ошибка получения квот!');
                    }
                }
            ]
```

Comment: How is this different from [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29237963/1810243)?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev, first - your answer is not what I'm looking for, second - the question about different subject. Thanks.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev Looking at his second select, the default option has no val and will return an empty string. In actuality, none of the data params are "working", but he only noticed the missing one and not the incorrect ones.

Comment: @slicedtoad Yes, I tried to get clarification on what was wrong with the parameters and where he was trying to apply these options in the other question (which has been deleted), but I think you got the problem/solution. In older versions of fullCalendar, I just removed and then reattached the events sources to accomplish the same thing, but this way (v 1.6.3+) seems a lot better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is the Dynamic data parameter ([2nd from bottom](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/))

Your code above is getting `$("select[name='depplace'] option:selected").val()` when the fullcalendar is initialized instead of every time the JSON feed is queried.

```
url: "@Url.Content("~/Home/GetQuota")",
data: function() { //runs every time the JSON script is called.
    return {
        pax: $("select[name='pax'] option:selected").val(),
        fromtype: $("select[name='depplace'] option:selected").attr("name"),
        fromcode: $("select[name='depplace'] option:selected").val(),
        totype: $("select[name='arrplace'] option:selected").attr("name"),
        tocode: $("select[name='arrplace'] option:selected").val(),
        airservice: $("input[name='tariffs']").val()  
    };
}
```